# Create associations between entities Doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to connect 2 entities and I am having troubles with it.
I have two classes: User and Gender.
Each User is from a kind gender (male or female). At my database I have two tables with this structure:

```
 user(**id**, firstName, gender);
 gender(**id**, type);
```

Now I have created two entities at my system. User.php and Gender.php

## User

```
<?php  

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="User")
 **/

class User
{
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 **/  
private $id;

 /**
 * @Column(type="string")
 **/
private $firstName;

 /**
 * @Column(type="string")
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gender")
 * @JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="type")
 * @var Gender[]
 **/
private $gender;

 
public function __construct($content) {
    $this->setContent($content);
}   


/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
 
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->firstName;
}

  /**
 * @return int
 */
public function getGender() {
    return $this->gender;
}
 
 

/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setFirstName($content) {
    $this->firstName = (string) $content;
}

/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setGender($content) {
    $this->gender = (string) $content;
}
 
}
```

## Gender

```
<?php  

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="Gender")
 **/

class Gender
{
/**
 * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
 **/  
private $id;

 /**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="gender")
 * @JoinColumn(name="gender", referencedColumnName="gender")
 * @Column(type="string")
 **/
private $type;


/**
 * @param integer $content
 * 
 */
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param string $content
 * 
 */
public function getType() {
    return $this->type;
}


/**
 * @param string $content
 */
public function setGender($content) {
    $this->gender = (string) $content;
}
 
}
```

What I want is to get the gender type when I get a User, so both entities have to be connected by gender-type attributes.
I have tried to do so with **@ManyToOne** or **@JoinColumn** features, but I couldn't get it.

How can I do it? What I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this in User Class:

```
* @JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="type")
```

with that :

```
 * @JoinColumn(name="gender", referencedColumnName="type")
```

Your field name is gender, not type in User table.

In Gender class use only:

```
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="gender")
```

Comment: I have done it but... where should i get the Gender type? after getting the data with: $dql = "SELECT a FROM user a"; $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
$users = $query->getResult();

if i do a print_r($users); i dont't get it.

Comment: I've done it but now... where i see the type data? i don't get it on the $users variable. How i access the Gender class data?

Comment: iterate through users and get $user->gender

Comment: Yeah but like that i only get the gendery ID, not the gendery type of the gender table.

Answer (score 0):

Might be offtopic but Gender table is useless. You will always have just 2 (male/female) so no point in doing this.

You should create new column in User table, type=integer and use 0/1 for gender. Use constants like

```
Class User
{
   const MALE=0 ;
   const FEMALE=1 ;

  .... ORM definition...

 public function isMale()
 {
     return $this->getGender() == self::MALE ;
 }
```

And in controller:

```
if ( !$user->isMale() ) {
    .... buy shoes ....
} else {
    .... buy beer ....
}
```

Or similar. Because you only have 2 options, only one function is needed.

Comment: I've designed the system the more modular and extendable possible. If i want to add or change the name of the gender, or maybe add a description or anything else to that table, it is better to have it in other table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the gender relation if you want to get if from the query.

```
$dql = "SELECT a,g FROM user a LEFT JOIN a.gender g";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setMaxResults(30);
$users = $query->getResult();
```